# Hadoop merge files

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have ran a map only job  with 674 mappers which hive took an has generated 674  .gz files I want to merge these files to aroung 30-35 files.have tried hive megre mapfilse property by not getting the merged output

Answer (score 13):

Try using `TEZ` execution engine and then `hive.merge.tezfiles`. You might also want to specify the size as well.

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez; -- TEZ execution engine
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true; -- Notifying that merge step is required
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000000; --128MB
set hive.merge.size.per.task=128000000; -- 128MB
```

If you want to go with `MR` engine then add following settings (I haven't tried it personally)

```
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true; -- Notifying that merge step is required
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000000; --128MB
set hive.merge.size.per.task=128000000; -- 128MB
```

Above setting will spawn one more step to merge the files and approx size of each part file should be 128MB.

Reference:

- [Settings description](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)